# How to convert xpt file into sas file by xpt2loc?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I tried to convert a xpt file called "ae.xpt" into sas file called ae as well. The original file was saved at "D:\sdtm\data_xpt", and I want the converted sas file to be saved at "D:\sdtm\data_sas".

Here was my code, but it didn't work:

```
libname sasfiles 'D:\sdtm\data_sas';

%let Root=D:\sdtm\data_xpt;
%xpt2loc(libref=sasfiles, memlist=ae, filespec='&root\ae.xpt');
```

How to write the correct one? Thanks!

Comment: Macro variables need double quotes around them not single quotes. Also, please include the log with macro options when you run into these issues.

Comment: Closing as dup of the macro variable resolve generic... if it turns out there's more issues other than &root not resolving to the full filename/path, please edit the Q to include a log.